# Como obtener una columna con el numero de orden de cada registro de una consulta en MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Deseo obtener el número de cada registro de una consulta en MYSQL en una columna adicional, de esa misma consulta.
[image: Por ejemplo, en esta imagen tengo el listado de estudiantes con sus promedios escolares. Ya está ordenado de mayor a menor, quiero obtener su puesto (1,2,3) sin necesidad de recorrerlo con un while en me aplicación web.]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta así:

```sql
select t.*, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
from tutabla as t, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
where ...
```

---

**EDIT:**

```sql
select t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY bol_nota) as Orden
from tutabla as t
where ...
```

Comment: Me los ordena, pero según el nombre del estudiante y no según el promedio escolar. Necesitaría que agregue ese numero según el orden que ya tengo en la consulta.

Comment: Estás trabajando con qué versión de MySQL?

Comment: Ver 8.0.29 for Win64 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)

Comment: Genial. A partir de la versión 8.0 de MySQL ya está la función ROW_NUMBER(); acabo de editar la respuesta.

Comment: Excelente.  Muchas gracias.